# How to change the color of nav menu, when scrolling

Tags: javascript, svg

How to do it like this menu, when it slides to a different place. Will change the text color??

reference:
https://markus.se/

Comment: look into SVG to create that effect

Comment: into svg? Is there a similar tutorial that can help me?

Comment: css `mix-blend-mode` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Answer (score 0):

set mix-blend-mode css of text.

```css
.div {
    border:1px solid #eee;
    height:700px;
}
.fixed{
    position:fixed;
    font-size:30px;
    mix-blend-mode:difference;
    color: antiquewhite;
}
.a{
    background-color:red;
}
.b{
    background-color:blue;
}
.c{
    background-color:yellow;
}
.d{
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="fixed">Text</div>
<div class="div a"></div>
<div class="div b"></div>
<div class="div c"></div>
<div class="div d"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Isn't it just put mix-blend-mode in css of text?

Comment: @heyyo99 .. yes.

Comment: But I put it in the text of the menu, and nothing happens. Did I put it in the wrong place, or what is the problem?

Comment: @heyyo99 .. please addd what you tried in the questions so it will be easy to understand where your are actually stuck.